# pkcs11engine doesn't logout after engine cleanup()

Tags: python, logout, m2crypto, pkcs#11

I want to do the following:

1. Generate key pair on security token (I use Aladdin tokens) (PyKCS11)
2. Generate PKCS#10 request (I use M2Crypto + engine_pkcs11 for it) and send it to CA.
3. Receive signed X.509 certificate from CA and write it to security token.

Request generation is done like this:

```py
    def generate_request(
        self, uid, cn=None, user_pin=None, keyid=TOKEN_TEMP_KEY_ID):
    """Generate PKCS#10 certificate request
    @param keyid: ID of key to use for certificate request generation
    @type keyid: str
    @param uid: UID to put in request subject distinguished name
    @type uid: str
    @param cn: Common name (if any) of subject to use for certificate
    request generation
    @type cn: str
    @param user_pin: user PIN code. User privileges are required for
    signing of certificate request
    @type user_pin: str
    @return PKCS10 request in PEM format signed by token's private key
    """
    Engine.load_dynamic()
    e = Engine.Engine('dynamic')
    e.ctrl_cmd_string('SO_PATH', PKCS11_ENGINE_PATH)
    e.ctrl_cmd_string('LIST_ADD', '1')
    e.ctrl_cmd_string('LOAD', None)
    e.ctrl_cmd_string('MODULE_PATH', PKCS11_LIBRARY_PATH)
    a = Engine.Engine('pkcs11')
    a.init()
    # Hex-encoded key id should be provided to that function
    k = a.load_private_key(hexlify(keyid), pin=user_pin)
    req = X509.Request()
    subject_name = PKCS10_DN_PREFIX + (('UID', MBSTRING_ASC, uid, -1, -1, 0),)
    if cn:
        subject_name = subject_name + (('CN', MBSTRING_ASC, cn, -1, -1, -1),)
    name = X509.X509_Name()
    for entry in subject_name:
        name.add_entry_by_txt(*entry)
    req.set_subject(name)
    req.set_pubkey(k)
    req.sign(k, 'sha1')
    reqpem = req.as_pem()
    Engine.cleanup()
    return reqpem
```

Here is the code that writes certificate to security token:

```py
def write_certificate(self, cert_pem, so_pin):
    """Write certificate to token
    @param cert_pem: certificate in pem format
    @type cert_pem: str
    @param so_pin: PIN code of security officer
    @type so_pin: str
    """
    cert = X509.load_cert_string(cert_pem)
    if cert.check_ca(): # What label to use?
        label = TOKEN_CA_CERT_LABEL
    else:
        label = TOKEN_USER_CERT_LABEL
    tCert = (
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_CLASS, PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKC_X_509),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_TOKEN, True),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_PRIVATE, False),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_LABEL, label),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_ID, make_key_id(cert.get_pubkey())),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_SUBJECT, cert.get_subject().as_der()),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_ISSUER, cert.get_issuer().as_der()),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, cert.get_serial_number()),
        (PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKA_VALUE, cert.as_der()))
    s = self.lib.openSession(self.slot, PyKCS11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    s.login(so_pin, PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKU_SO)
    s.createObject(tCert)
    s.logout()
    s.closeSession()
```

The problem is that after request generation i get CKR_USER_ANOTHER_ALREADY_LOGGED_IN error. I looked into engine_pkcs11 source code and in engine_pkcs11.c (https://github.com/OpenSC/engine_pkcs11/blob/master/src/engine_pkcs11.c) file there is a function called `static EVP_PKEY *pkcs11_load_key`. It's quite long so here is a part of it:

```c
    /* Now login in with the (possibly NULL) pin */
    if (PKCS11_login(slot, 0, pin)) {
        /* Login failed, so free the PIN if present */
        if (pin != NULL) {
            OPENSSL_cleanse(pin, pin_length);
            free(pin);
            pin = NULL;
            pin_length = 0;
        }
        fail("Login failed\n");
    }
```

So, as i understand login is performed when key is used (PKCS#10 request generation requires key). If login is performed then i believe corresponding logout should be performed also, but i couldn't find. Here is source of ENGINE_finish() function:

```c
int pkcs11_finish(ENGINE * engine)
{
    if (ctx) {
    PKCS11_CTX_unload(ctx);
    PKCS11_CTX_free(ctx);
    ctx = NULL;
}
if (pin != NULL) {
    OPENSSL_cleanse(pin, pin_length);
    free(pin);
    pin = NULL;
    pin_length = 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow (maybe implicitly) make logout from security token on step 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could do it like this:

Before loading engine I open new session and login into it
After i finished working i close sessions (using closeSession() is not enough)

So request generation is done like this.

```
    s = self.lib.openSession(self.slot, PyKCS11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    s.login(user_pin)
    Engine.load_dynamic()
```

...
and i added after Engine cleanup

```
    a.finish()
    Engine.cleanup()        
    s.logout()
    s.closeAllSessions()
```

I also had to do some patching to Session class in PyKCS11 source code because there is a typo (closeAllSession instead of closeAllSessions):

```
def closeAllSessions(self):
    """
    C_CloseAllSessions
    """
    rv = self.lib.C_CloseAllSessions(self.slot)
    if rv != CKR_OK:
        raise PyKCS11Error(rv)
```

Hope that this helps